# What component to use to make object levitate

Tags: fan

imagine you have a printed circuit board. I'd like to put a component at each corner of the PCB that would create air, something like a fan, but powerful enough to be able to make the PCB levitate. In fine, the component must be as small as possible but for the beginning the size does not really matter.

I'm not sure that I have to use a fan because it could be not enough powerful. In fact, I really don't know what to use and if such component exists or not.

Does somebody have a lead on that ?

(from comments:)
As I (Flup) understand it the idea is to make a soft landing for the PCB when it falls on the floor.

Comment: Use magnets, why not?

Comment: Size and weight of the PCB?

Comment: You're doing this backwards: you start with a solution (the fan) and then ask a question.

Comment: How that ? At a T time, the PCB should just lie on the floor. Then, you can have an event that trigger the levitation. I don't reject your answer, I just don't understand. I'll explain exactly what I want to do. I want to place an accelerometer on the PCB and if the PCB falls, I want the accelerometer to notice it and make THE COMPONENT react in order to cushion the fall. I thought that air was the best idea but could be not. Using magnets would use the electromagnetism, wouldn't it ? So it is applicable ?

Comment: Try googling quadcopters

Comment: Yeah ok but quadcopters use propellers, I'd like something more small at the end. Notice that the object to make levitate won't  weight more than 200g.

Comment: If the PCB doesn't actually have to float freely then use solenoids.

Comment: Hello, I'll investigate on solenoids. During this time, I add a precision. The main principle would be that the PCB has to land. At the final stage of the project, I should be enable to drop the PCB and it should land softly whatever its position.

Comment: That's... I don't even have a word for that. "Unrealistic" doesn't cut it.

Comment: If the PCB normally sits on a 70cm high table, tie it to the table top with a 60cm wire. If it falls off the table it will magically levitate 10cm above the floor.

Comment: @Ignacio - This is so queer that there isn't even a category for flagging it.

Comment: Hey, another joke, nice one... Is it just a joke or my idea is really that stupid ? Another unrelated question. I started my question with "Hello", but it keeps on being stripped... Is it normal ?

Comment: Yes, Hello's, thanks, and greetings are not allowed in questions or answers.

Comment: Apple actually has a patent on this for mobile phones. Little bursts of air that shoot out just before the phone hits the ground when dropped... Perhaps some commenters are lacking in imagination.

Comment: Funny, that's exactly what I'm trying to do... I have some difficulties to think that it is strictly impossible but anyway... I'm not advanced enough to argue with expert ;-)

Comment: The bursts of air could only reorient it though, not cushion it much less make it levitate.

Comment: @geometrikal  Do you know the pat. number?  A patent like that should be entertaining.

Comment: Sorry got it wrong, it was amazon.   http://www.slashgear.com/amazon-ceo-jeff-bezos-filed-to-patent-airbags-for-smartphones-12171533/.  Apples one uses jets or motors to orient the device on an edge to reduce screen cracking... Not like any will ever be made though!

Comment: I am picturing 4 tiny parachutes that pop open from the corners of the device. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can levitate a PCB in two ways: One, like a hovercraft, with fans. Two, like a maglev train, with magnetic repulsion. Neither solution is going to break any significant fall. Moreover, the first two proposed solutions require a vertical guide of some sort (else the unit will move horizontally and fall or tip over).

If you are talking about a handheld device, it would typically be at least several inches from the floor, if the unit falls it will gain velocity at 9.8m/s^2, and within a few milliseconds no practical levitation technology will overcome its inertia. Likewise you won't be able to build in airbags.

Your best shot at protecting the unit from fall damage is adequate cushioning. Try designing an enclosure that will cushion a raw egg dropped from a tall building and you'll be on the right track.

If you need the unit to fall only on one side, you could attach it to a piece of buttered toast, or to the back of a cat.

Comment: Mmmmh, I was a bit afraid to read that kind of answer. I'm a beginner and I wasn't sure that it would even be possible. I'll keep on thinking about it even if your answer kind of convinced me that it is not feasible. 

Nice joke by the way ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do sounds unrealistic.  Do the math.

The time it takes a object to fall a particular distance from rest is:

T = sqrt(2 D / g)

where D is the distance and g the accelleration due to gravity.  On earth where g = 9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>, T is 640 ms for a height of 2 meters, and 450 ms for a height of 1 meter.  So basically you get half a second, if you're lucky, from the time you detect free fall until splat.

Note that the time you have to react and start producing significant upwards force is much less than these value.  It does no good to start pushing upwards 2 mm off the ground.  Even if you could miraculously produce enough upwards force so that the velocity reaches 0 just as the device touches the ground, it would still be undergoing large accellerations, which was the goal to prevent in the first place.

To subject the object to only 2g, you have to start producing that 2g half way to the ground.  For a 1 m drop height, that means you need 2g upwards thrust by the time it drops 500 mm, which is 319 ms.  Can you spin up your thrusters to full speed in 319 ms?  That would take very special and expensive motors and a lot of power.  That in turn takes weight, which makes the thrust required larger, which means more power and larger motors, etc.

Note that none of this has to do with electronics, just very basic high school physics.

Comment: Actually, even 2 mm _could_ make a big difference -- imagine dropping an iPhone with or without a 2 mm layer of foam padding around it. Although that thought experiment also highlights the fact that it's not just the acceleration that matters, but also how the force is distributed across the object.